# Puppet: Accessing var/val of more complex hieradata yaml files

Tags: centos, puppet

I've been Googling around and haven't seen any examples of a more complex hieradata yaml config. Consider this:

```
# /path/to/hieradata/vhost/config.yaml
vhost_config_melikedev:
  port: 53002
  framework: wordpress
  static_asset_dirs:
    - wp-content

vhost_config_melikedrinks:
  port: 53001
  framework: symfony
  static_asset_dirs:
    - image
    - js
    - css
```

How would I access the port value for the `vhost_config_melikedev` entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the guys in #puppet on irc.freenode.net. You can do what I was asking by referencing the values like this:

```
#/path/to/modules/nginx/manifests/vhost/conf.pp
define touch($app_primary, $app_sub) {

    ....

    $vhost_config_data = hiera("vhost_config_${name}")

    $tpl_port = $vhost_config_data[port]

    ....
}
```

You can also reference the values using the info outlined here: https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/271/a-heira-example-with-complicated-data/